# Other referenced package cannot be found in test

Tags: unit-testing, android-studio, android-gradle-plugin

In my project (if you want detailed information, you can find it [on Github](https://github.com/Xilconic/Dice-Statistics)) I've got two modules:

- app (the default module generated when you start out with a new Android project)
- dice (new module, which is a dice rolling domain model package)

I've started out fleshing out my MVP classes in the app module, and I want to reuse the `PredefinedRandomIntegerGenerator` class ([on Github](https://github.com/Xilconic/Dice-Statistics/blob/master/dice/src/test/java/com/xilconic/gaming/dice/test/mocks/PredefinedRandomIntegerGenerator.java)) from the dice `module` (residing the `test` folder of that module) in my unit tests in the `app` module.

When I started writing my test code I encountered no problems, until I started running my

```
C:\Projects\Dice-Statistics\app\src\test\java\com\xilconic\dicestatistics\viewmodels\SixSidedDieRollingViewModelTest.java:5: error: package com.xilconic.gaming.dice.test.mocks does not exist
import com.xilconic.gaming.dice.test.mocks.PredefinedRandomIntegerGenerator;
                                          ^
C:\Projects\Dice-Statistics\app\src\test\java\com\xilconic\dicestatistics\viewmodels\SixSidedDieRollingViewModelTest.java:21: error: cannot find symbol
        RandomIntegerGenerator rng = new PredefinedRandomIntegerGenerator(results);
                                         ^
  symbol:   class PredefinedRandomIntegerGenerator
  location: class SixSidedDieRollingViewModelTest
```

I have no clue why during the build the com.xilconic.gaming.dice.test.mocks package can't be found. Am I missing something in my Gradle script for the `app` module? That looks as follows:

```
apply plugin: 'com.android.application'

android {
    compileSdkVersion 23
    buildToolsVersion "23.0.2"

    defaultConfig {
        applicationId "com.xilconic.dicestatistics"
        minSdkVersion 8
        targetSdkVersion 23
        versionCode 1
        versionName "1.0"
    }
    buildTypes {
        release {
            minifyEnabled false
            proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android.txt'), 'proguard-rules.pro'
        }
    }
}

dependencies {
    compile fileTree(include: ['*.jar'], dir: 'libs')
    testCompile 'junit:junit:4.12'
    compile 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:23.1.1'
    compile 'com.android.support:design:23.1.1'
    compile project(':dice')
}
```

Any help would be very welcome!